# Office 2016 Comatibility with Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, office-2016

I am looking for a summary or list of compatibility issues between working with Microsoft Office 2016 files and SharePoint 2010. Does anyone know if such a summary exists?

Comment: Did you check this? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/378d10e7-156d-4bac-9882-31f6b2e822c0/sharepoint-2010-and-office-2016?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

The best I have been able to discover is this: it depends on whether you are running Microsoft Office 32 bit or 64 bit. It seems Microsoft Office 2016 - 32 bit works just fine with SharePoint 2010, it is the 64-bit version that seems to cause all the issues.